# what does the line "/mifs/.;/services/LogService" mean

Tags: exploit, cve

I am trying to understand the CVE-2020-15505 - [RCE on MobileIron MDM]

from some references like:
https://blog.orange.tw/2020/09/how-i-hacked-facebook-again-mobileiron-mdm-rce.html

they all start there exploit by using "POST /mifs/.;/services/LogService".
my question is, what is the mean of this request?

Answer (score 2):

`/mifs/` is the webroot of MobileIron
`/services/LogService` is the vulnerable endpoint of Hessian Deserialization

About the `/.;/`, you can refer my [Breaking Parser Logic](https://blog.orange.tw/2018/08/how-i-chained-4-bugs-features-into-rce-on-amazon.html) research in 2018